# How do I calculate the year from (new Date).getTime()

Tags: javascript

This should be simple math buy I just can't deduce it at the moment.
getTime() should return a unix time stamp in milli-seconds and from there one should be able to figure out the year.

```
function theYear(timestamp){
    // answer
    return year;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
 var year = new Date(timestamp).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function theYear(timestamp){    
    return new Date(timestamp).getYear();
}
```

Comment: `.getFullYear()` is preferred over `.getYear()`. From the ES6 spec draft: "The getFullYear method is preferred for nearly all purposes, because it avoids the “year 2000 problem."

Comment: Roger that. The comment is useful for others!